# Check to see if a list is a subset of another list only if number of appearances for items match

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm aware of subsets and how they can find if a list matches with another list but I've realised that my code doesn't account for repeating letters.

```
word = ["b", "e", "e"]
given_letters = ["b", "e", "p", "w"]

if set(word).issubset(given_letters): 
    print("Within the given letters' limits.")
```

This would print out the sentence I placed but I don't want it to because it's not an exact match.

Basically, I want it to accept ['b', 'e'] because it matches the number of times 'e' appeared but reject ['b', 'e', 'e'] because that list contains one more 'e' than there is in 'given_letters'.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: When you turn a **list** into a **set**, you lose any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest approach with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

def is_sublist(check_list, base_list):
    base_list_counter = Counter(base_list)
    check_list_counter = Counter(check_list)
    for letter, occurances in check_list_counter.items():
        if occurances > base_list_counter[letter]:
            return False
    return True

assert not is_sublist(["b", "e", "e"], ["b", "e", "p", "w"])
assert is_sublist(["b", "e", "e"], ["b", "e", "e", "p", "w"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
word = ["b", "e", "e"]
given_letters = ["b", "e", "p", "w"]

def check(given_letters, word):
    for i in set(given_letters):
        if i in word:
            if given_letters.count(i) != word.count(i):      #Check if element count is greater than 1. 
                return False
    return True

print(check(given_letters, word))
```

Comment: And sure it fails when `given_letters = ["b", "e", "e", "p", "w"]`

Comment: @vishes_shell. Thanks updated snippet.

Comment: Why `if i in word:`? This will result in false positives

Comment: Yuck, an O(n^2) solution. Should be using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of `.count()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right and you are looking for one-liner :

```
word = ["b", "e", "e"]
given_letters = ["b", "e", "p", "e","w"]
if(all(True if word.count(item) <= given_letters.count(item) else False for item in word)):
    print("Within the given letters' limits.")
else:
    print ("Whatever you want")
```

Comment: `True if word.count(item) <= given_letters.count(item) else False` is the same thing as just `word.count(item) <= given_letters.count(item)` :/